# Where did extra space come from in html of Struts app?

Tags: java, html, struts, space

I'm debugging a Struts Java app, in my defaultLayout.tag file there are 2 tables, there is no space between them, but in the result html which I saw from Firefox's source code Inspector, there are 2 lines of:

```
<Br></Br>
<Br></Br>
```

I wonder where in the Struts app did it generate those 2 extra line of breaks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Spring MVC does not generate HTML by itself, it uses external views to do that. It looks like in your case it's a taglib which generated the HTML in question, so I'd look there.

Comment: @dimoniy : Thanks, but in my case, how do I find out which program used the DefaultLayout.tag to generate the html ?

Comment: find controller for the URL you see on the screen and then you can find view name from that.

Comment: @dimoniy : Correction, it's a struts app not Spring, I found the url, it's "news.do", but when I did a search for "news.do", only found some jsp's that use the DefaultLayout.tag and generated the string "news.do", and the jsp didn't generate the break lines.

Comment: look at the tag declaration and find the place which generates the extra line breaks.

Comment: @Frank In the result html tags generated by JSP may appear anywhere in the document ;)

Comment: There's nothing here anybody can use to help. You must find the JSP(s) and/or tags that are generating the HTML.

Answer (score -2):

In css add : br { display: none; }

Comment: Instead of finding where the problem comes from, you just disable all of the `<br/>` on the page?

Comment: Yes, that's the most efficient way to this problem. If you know where those breaks come from and how to prevent them from generating, I'd like to know.