# How to ignore 2 break lines in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm debugging an existing Java/JSP/Struts application, somehow it generates 2 break lines and left a large space in the page :

```
<Br></Br>
<Br></Br>
```

So I searched around and found I can use the following in CSS to ignore break lines :

```
br { display: none; }
```

See my previous question : [Where did extra space come from in html of Struts app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632412/where-did-extra-space-come-from-in-html-of-struts-app)

But this will cause all break lines to be ignored in the app, and not the ideal solution I'm looking for, I think the br's were generated by Struts and hard to control, so I wonder if there is a way in CSS to define 2 breaks as nothing [to be ignored], maybe something like this ?

```
brbr { display: none; }
br.br { display: none; }
```

I tried it, didn't work, must be in wrong format, any CSS experts here can answer my question ?

Comment: `brbr` will match tags with that name, and `br.br` will match elements with name `br` which have class `br`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
br + br {display:none;}
```

This selects a `br` that directly follows another `br` using the `+` selector.

**Ref:** [Section 5.1 Pattern matching](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) and [5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` in your selector:

```
br + br { display: none; }
```

---

[From W3 Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

> `E + F` : Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.

Answer (score 1):

br supports class why not give then a class

```
<br class="hey" />
```

CSS

```
.hey{
display:none;
}
```